# Why does the Channel Tunnel enter the ground around 10 km from the coast?

Tags: civil-engineering, geotechnical-engineering, rail, tunnels

I know that digging tunnels is always *much* more costly than building ways or train above ground.

Why doesn't the Channel Tunnel start around the coastline? Why does it have an around 10 km long portion under land on the British side?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The picture, below, of the exaggerated long section of the Channel Tunnel was taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Channel_Tunnel).

[image]

<sub>Full-sized image [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Channel_Tunnel_geological_profile_1.svg).</sub>

Some of the limiting factors for the Channel Tunnel are:

- Railways don't like steep gradients
- The tunnels comprising the Channel Tunnel were excavated using tunnel
  boring machines (TBMs). Like railways, they cannot tolerate steep
  gradients.
- The tunnel was excavated in chalk marl (green coloured material in
  the picture). This was due to its depth (not being too shallow and
  not being too deep) and its ability to be easily dug but also it
  would cause major support issues for the tunnels.

If you look at the long section of the tunnel there is some high ground on both coasts. The width of the high ground on the French side is about 2 to 3 km, whereas on the English side the width about 7 to 8 km.

For reasons of maintaining a comfortable gradient for the TBMs and the rail line and to position the tunnels in the lower part of the chalk marl combined with the width of the high ground on the coast and where the chalk marl is located within the high ground and because the chalk marl is inclined on the English side of the tunnel, the portal for the tunnel on the  English side had to be positioned some 9 to 10 km from the coast.

Comment: Actually a tunnel boring machine can tolerate gradients which are steeper than ones acceptable for railroads. The key is steep gradient is a problem - a lot of power is needed and wheels slippage can occur.

Comment: To add a few numbers to this, the usual maximum gradient for a railway is 1:80, and the tunnel averages 45m below sea-level. Add in 100m of cliff and it's easy to reach 10km

Comment: It's not only the entrance that's underground.  Much of the route from London is also in tunnels. See [High Speed 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Speed_1) Chanel Tunnel Rail Link chart near top at right of Wikipedia page.